# Mediawiki extension used in a model with parameters

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm using Mediawiki 1.18.1 and the anyweb extension. All is working well.
I'm trying to replace a chunk of several pages by a model (protected against edition)
The chunk I'm replacing use an extension (anyweb) and looks like:

```
<anyweb  mywidth="100%" myheight="170">http://barbules.fr/warGAE/RASP/rasp.php?lat=50.028055555555554&lon=1.3005555555555557&good=NO,</anyweb>
```

I'm trying to replace it by a model like this:
{{Meteo|lat=50.028055555555554|lon=1.3005555555555557|good=SSO,}}
where the page Model:Meteo contains, for example:

```
<anyweb  mywidth="100%" myheight="170">http://barbules.fr/warGAE/RASP/rasp.php?lat={{{lat|0.0}}}&lon={{{lon|0.0}}}&good=NO,</anyweb>
```

but the lat and lon variables are not evaluated by the model before passing to the anyweb extension; so the extension get as lat value {{{lat|0.0}}} in place of 50.028055555555554

Is it possible to use parameters of a model as part of an extension? How?

Comment: Please upgrade your MediaWiki. This version is antiquated and unsafe to run.

Answer (score 0):

Extension tags contents are processed as-is (the parser can't know whether `{{}}` has special meaning in a tag). Use the `#tag` magic function to turn the tag into a template (sort of):

```
{{#tag|anyweb|<anyweb  mywidth="100%" myheight="170">http://barbules.fr/warGAE/RASP/rasp.php?lat={{{lat|0.0}}}&lon={{{lon|0.0}}}&good=NO,|mywidth=100%|myheight=170}}
```